# .env.local file and npm run build in vite react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite, api-key, .env

I have built a Vite React app with Firebase as a database, after deploying it I opened the deployed website and it worked correctly although I did not add env vars to the hosting.

so my question is: does the npm run build command merges the .env.local file with the app files inside the dist folder? and if it does is this practice secure?

#edit
I also restricted the API to work only on specific domains from console.cloud.google.com but it's still working on localhost and other environments.